# I forgot my SSL passphrase, any advice?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

My server rebooted, and apache is now asking me for the passphrase. I have no clue what the passphrase is, especially considering I never opt for the passphrase.

Is there anything I can do? I imagine somehow removing it without knowing the original is probably out of the question. I'm more asking for what the nexts that I would have to do to get the site back running.

Comment: Hmm.  Restore the SSL private key from backup (and see if it's changed recently)?  If it's properly encrypted, you're probably going to wind up generating a new certificate and key.  Just to note, you can get a free certificate relatively quickly from, say, StartSSL which will be good for a year. Depending on what you're doing, that may be enough to get you up and running while you figure out what to do with the old cert/key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the certificate self-signed or signed by CA? if the former you need to generate a new one, and if the latter you should contact your vendor CA support. or you just have to purchase a new one from some vendor if you do need a CA-signed one.

Comment: in the new one, either store passphrase in a safe vault, or just remove it, which most servers do as the passphrase prevents automated restarts.